# How to make UPDATE queries in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I like using LINQ to SQL. The only problem is that I don't like the default way of updating tables.

Let's say I have the following table with the following columns:

```
ID (primary key), value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

When I need to update something I call

```
UPDATE ... WHERE ID=@id
```

LINQ to SQL calls

```
UPDATE ... WHERE ID=@id and value1=@value1 and value2=@value2 and value3=@value3 and value4=@value4 and value5=@value5
```

I can override this behavior by adding

```
UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never
```

to every column, but with every update of the DataContext class with the GUI, this will be erased. Is there any way to tell LINQ to use this way of updating data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused by this statement:

> but with every update of the DataContext class with the GUI, this will be erased. Is there any way to tell LINQ to use this way of updating data?

By "the GUI", do you mean the Linq to SQL designer?  Because the property sheet for each member has an "Update Check" property that you can set to "Never".  If you are manually editing the `.designer.cs` file, don't do that, instead change the `Update Check` setting in the *actual* designer.

[Designer Screen http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7912/updatecheckdesigner.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7912/updatecheckdesigner.png)

Please note: The "default way" of updating used by Linq to SQL is called [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), and is a way of preventing conflicting updates from multiple users.  If you turn this off by using the method above, you have to be prepared to deal with the fact that if two users have the same record open at the same time, the second user's changes will overwrite the first user's changes without any warning or confirmation.  Be sure that this is the behaviour you really want.

Comment: Yes, but it fails in situations where you are using (for example) a timestamp column

Comment: @Rob Sanders: `rowversion` columns (AKA `timestamp`) are special.  There's a reason for the name.  They should not be a part of your schema unless you plan to use them for replication or synchronization (in which case they should not be included in the DBML) or for concurrency control (in which case you always want the update check).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what rowversion columns are for.  Fact is, L2S allows you to add them to the DBML, so it's worth knowing about the impact on LS2's concurrency model

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's not.  You have to edit the DBML manually after it is generated (or updated) - which is a pain (or use the Designer as already mentioned in the other answer).

When I last used L2S on a project, I wrote a quick utility which ran post-generation and fixed it up, but it's an unnecessary pain which (c)shouldn't be required IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this one myself. The trick is to change the way one generates the DBML--such as using [l2st4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/). Then you can set that pesky UpdateCheck property to always be never by modifying the template.

Answer (score 0):

That is how Linq works. Why don't you like this update behavior?

Read about optimistic concurrency

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373.aspx